# Game engine design: clean flow of actions between clients and server

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, game-engine

I am designing a multiplayer online game for the sake of learning.

Several clients connect to a server that contains the true representation of the game world. Every client keeps track of a subset of that representation. I store the representations in a `Context`. The clients and the server change the state of the global context by passing various action classes around. One example is the `MoveEntityAction`, another is the `TalkAction`, and they all implement an interface called `Action`. In principle, the game is played by a flow of `Action` instances.

However, passing actions back and forth requires some fiddling. First, provide a definition of how they are read and written to the network. Second, protocol to translate them back and forth between the global and local contexts (different coordinate systems, etc). Third, let the server determine which actions need to preceed another action (I hope that is made clear by the pseudo-code below).

Right now, this process relies on several helper classes, each implementing an interface called `Writer`, `Reader`, `ContextSwitcher` and `PrerequisiteFinder`.

This has made me do the following:

- Create a lookup table, `ActionLibrary`, that defines methods such as `getReader(int actionId)`, `getWriter(<Class <? extends Action> a)`, etc.
- The classes that implement the helper interfaces are highly dependent on their associated `Action` class.

My game will have quite many classes implementing the `Action` interface, which means that every such class would require the implementation of 3 additional helper classes, each containing the protocol for dealing with a specific action. For example, `MoveEntityReader`, `MoveEntityWriter`, `MoveEntityContextSwitcher`, `MoveEntityPrerequisiteFinder`.

In spite of trying to adhere to the single responsibility principle, **this approach does not feel very flexible.** In fact, it feels quite awkward to distribute small pieces of protocol over several classes like this. And the `ActionLibrary` class does not feel like the best practice to associate these classes with each other.

---

Below is some example code of how an action might "flow" back and forth between the client and the server. Please note that this is pseudo-code written for this example, but hopefully it captures the essentials of what my real code does. In the below code, each Entity can be regarded as a client.

Human input (dragging and dropping an item on the screen) generates an instance of `moveEntityAction`. It is passed to the network stream as follows

```
writer = ActionLibrary.getWriter(moveEntityAction);
writer.writeTo(outputStream, moveEntityAction);
```

Server receives a packet with an ID and translates it to the global context, the servers representation of the game world:

```
reader = ActionLibrary.getReader(Id);
localAction = reader.readFrom(inputStream);
globalAction = ActionLibrary.getContextSwitcher(localAction.getClass(), playerContext, globalContext).apply(localAction);
```

After verifying that the action is OK, the server decides to broadcast the action to all the other clients. However, before it can do that it must broadcast the "prerequisites" of that action to every client. For example, if a `MoveEntityAction` moves an entity into the screen of a second entity, a `PlaceEntityAction` must be sent to the second entity first, so that it has an object to move. That happens as follows:

```
List<Entity> spectators = globalContext.getActionSpectators(globalAction);

for (Entity spectator : spectators) {
    List<Action> prerequisiteActions = ActionLibrary.getPrerequisiteFinder(globalAction.getClass()).get(spectator, globalAction, globalContext);
    spectatorContext = globalContext.getContextOf(spectator);

    // Broadcast prerequisite actions (if any)
    for (Action globalPreAction : prerequisiteActions) {
        localPreAction = ActionLibrary.getContextSwitcher(globalPreAction.getClass(), globalContext, spectatorContext).apply(globalPreAction);

        writer = ActionLibrary.getWriter(localPreAction);
        writer.writeTo(outputStream);
    }

    // Finally, send the instigating action:
    localAction = ActionLibrary.getContextSwitcher(globalAction.getClass(), globalContext, spectatorContext).apply(globalAction);

    writer = ActionLibrary.getWriter(localAction); 
    writer.writeTo(outputStream);
}

// Execute the action on the globalContext
globalContext = globalAction.execute(globalAction);
```

then, the client receives each packet and its id, finds the corresponding reader and applies that to its local `Context`:

```
reader = ActionLibrary.getReader(Id);
localAction = reader.readFrom(inputStream);
context = localAction.execute(context);
```

---

**I am basically looking for some thoughts and advice on the matter. How would you clean this mess up? Maybe there is a design pattern for situations like mine where I risk entangling myself with a bunch of helper classes.**

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I would like to avoid `Serializable` for several reasons. One being that the client might not be written in Java. Another being that I want to pick up a general best practice here because in time I might turn this into a private server for another game that I do not own the network protocol for.

Comment: Just reading part of your post, I think a big clean-up could come from using Java `Serializable` interface on all the network objects.  This would simplify all your readers and writers quite a bit.  Second I'd make the clients and the servers all use the same coordinate system.  Try to use different coordinate systems feels like shooting yourself in the foot, I can see it would be too much work.

Comment: Different coordinate systems were just an example. The actions may look different depending on the context they were viewed from. One entity might be partially blinded and thus unable to see who committed the action, but for other entities that may be totally clear. The context of an entity helps to transform a 'true' action to fit his perception of the world. I appreciate the tip, but if I were to use `Serializable`, I would only solve half the problem since I still need to be able to switch contexts and find prerequisite actions.

Comment: Solving half your problem is better than solving none of it. :-)  But also when you describe entities in different states and how they react to an input, it sounds like trying to put all of that logic in one big Context might also be part of the problem.  Look at making entities react to input based on their own state.  C.f. Mark Brown's video on "systemic" games: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnpAAX9CkIc

Comment: Yep! It's a good response, but I'd still like to avoid `Serializable` (see my edit in the question). Sorry for not being clear on that from the start. 

About the context: that's basically just a bunch of state variables of the gameworld. The global context is used as input for another class, which contains logic for selecting a subset of it. The subset being another context, the perspective of an entity (a player, a mob). The ContextSwitcher class I show above is basically a way to relate actions made in one context to that of another). I will have a look at that video! Thanks again.

Comment: I had a look at the video and while I found it quite interesting, but I am not sure if it's a solution to my problem. The entity inputs that he describes seem analogous to what I call a local context. In the case of a player entity, the context would also be used for rendering. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step is to start thinking in terms of your game instead of technical terms (writers, streams, ContextSwitchers, etc.).

For example, you want to create the Battle City game (tanks). One of the entities would be `Tank` and the first step is to define its `interface`:

```
interface Tank {
   void moveLeft();
   void moveRight();
   void moveTop();
   void moveBottom();
   void fire();
}
```

You can choose some "protocol" for connection with the server (for example, it can be `grpc with Bidirectional Streaming`). And for the protocol you you need to write implementation of your `Tank` `interface`:

```
class GrpcTank implements Tank {
   // fields and constructors
   void moveLeft() {...}
   void moveRight() {...}
   void moveTop() {...}
   void moveBottom() {...}
   void fire() {...}
}
```

Every invoke of methods sent an async message to the server.

The next step, I would define some class which getting actions from joystick and invoke the `Tank` method:

```
class Joystick {
   Tank tank;
   
   // thread loop catching buttons presses and invoke appropriate tank methods
}
```

We have the next flow (to the server): we press some button, joystick object catches it, joystick object invokes tank, tank sends an async message to the server.

The next step is to process messages from the server. For that I would use some thread that getting the async stream of changes and update the object with interface `State`:

```
interface State {
   List<TankPosition> tanks();
}
```

And you can have a `Display` object that encapsulate State and redraws it if state is changed.

---

**Let's summarize:**

1. Try to start thinking of the entities of your game.
2. Hide implementation details behind interfaces.
3. Use asynchronous bidirectional messaging (one part of the app sends events, others get changes and redraws them).